# Is there an optimized solution for tcpdump pulling a specific IP?

Tags: bash, shell-script, tcpdump

I made a script that runs `tcpdump` in the background:

```
nohup tcpdump -i $INTERFACENAME dst $IPC >> text.txt
```

And I made another script that pulls any IP address other than `$IP` from `text.txt`, but it's kinda messy and long (the script will read line by line, remove `$IP`, rewrite the line and then search for IPs using `detect="$(grep -oE \"\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{0-9{1,3}\b capture.txt)"`).

Does anyone have a better solution for extracting a certain IP address from a `tcpdump` log and placing it in a variable on Linux?

Comment: Instead of describing your code, [edit] your question, copy&paste the code and format it as a code block. When asking for an *optimized* solution describe what problems you have with your solution.

Comment: Yes, please [EDIT] your question, and shows us i) an example input file, ii) the output you want from that example and iii) the code you currently have.

Comment: Wait, are you just looking for `tcpdump -i $INTERFACENAME dst $IPC | grep -oE '\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{0-9{1,3}\b' | grep -v "$IPC"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "pull any IP address other then $IP"? Your tcpdump only monitors connections to $IPC, so which IP addresses are you expecting to see there (except for your local IP)? Unless the destination is of you local IP address, and you want to see which IPs connect to your machine? Maybe it's better for you to explain what is your end goal, and not how to make your specific implementation work. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @terdon in the grep part i want to get the IP other then the $IPC something like this 
grep -v "not the $IPC"
 
 ,,,,, @ aviro so in tcpdump log you will find 2 ip in each line "dst IP" and "src IP" i want to put the "src IP" in a variable not the the mentioned in dst $IPC ( its simple )

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question and add the things we asked for. And `grep -v $IPC` _is_ "grep not the IPC"

Comment: Also, by default, tcpdump resolves the hostname of the IP, and if it succeeds it shows the hostname and not the IP. You should really paste here a short example of the output of your tcpdump and show exactly what you're trying to do. I think you're complicating it too much, you could use awk/sed instead of grep. And last thing, what if there's a list of IPs? Do want the variable to have multiple IPs?

Comment: @aviro i will sorry about that i need to ask for permission first to post the script , thanks all again for replying , i will update asap

Comment: You could post a small equivalent script that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve. Provided it shows your issue and you can apply answers based on that script back to your real world situation that should be acceptable

Comment: I'd dump traffic to a pcap file with `tcpdump -w` then run `tcpdump -r` on that file with proper filter expression.